# Jersey (HK2) Session Scoped object

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs, hk2

Is there a way I can inject an object in a session scope into my resource classes? I want this object to be the same object for requests part of the same session (The Servlet container manages sessions for us, but internally Tomcat just sets a JSESSIONID cookie). I know I can use a Singleton scope, Request scope, and Per-lookup scope using their respective annotations. How can I get Jersey to store objects in session scope?

Comment: You're going to need to create your own scope and context. There isn't one officially available. You can look for a third-party implementation. If you can't find one, you will need to implement your own. Check out the examples linked here https://javaee.github.io/hk2/extensibility.html#adding-a-scope-and-context-to-the-system

Comment: If you are going to build your own context for this I would suggest looking at https://javaee.github.io/hk2/operations.html.  Operations are a way to quickly and easily build RequestScope type of Contexts